# Typescript, --outFile argument and "Cannot find module"

Tags: django, typescript

I'm trying to use vuejs/typescript with django and django-compressor.
I have this files

- /project-root/tsconfig.json
- /project-root/packages.json
- /project-root/static/main.ts

File content

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "strict": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
     }
}
```

packages.json

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.5.21",
        "vue-class-component": "^6.3.2",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^7.2.0"
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

So when I run command `tsc --outFile static/main.js --module amd static/main.ts` I got the following error `static/main.ts:1:17 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue'.`.
How to properly setup typescript and use it with --outFile argument?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you need to specify `moduleResolution` as `node` for TypeScript to look for and find node modules like `vue`.

You've set this option in your `tsconfig.json`, but `tsconfig.json` isn't considered when you manually run `tsc` on source files from the command line. You'd have to include the option as part of that command.

You probably want something like this:

```sh
tsc \
  --outFile static/main.js \
  --module amd \
  --moduleResolution node \
  static/main.ts
```